# ROS2 Java Examples : com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cannot invoke method split() on null object

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, ros2

I cloned [ROS2 Java examples](https://github.com/ros2-java/ros2_java_examples) and tried to build them with Gradle using Intelij, Gradle 6.3 and Java 14. However the following exception is thrown during the project import.
I have completed ROS2 installation and I can succesfully run examples in cpp and python.
I copy the complete stacktrace.
The ROS2 version in my computer is ros2-dashing-20200319-windows-amd64.

> - Exception is: com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException:
>   Cannot invoke method split() on null object   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:272)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:130)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:56)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:79)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:120)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:110)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.buildFinished(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:104)
>   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:382)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:364)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:352)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:339)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:231)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:150)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:325)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:235)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.buildFinished(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:184)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:127)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:189)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:60)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
>   at
>   org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:80)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:68)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
>   at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method split() on null
>   object    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:43)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:52)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
>   at
>   org.ros2.tools.gradle.JavaAmentPluginExtension.updateJavaDependencies(JavaAmentPluginExtension.groovy:58)
>   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
>   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrentN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:94)
>   at
>   org.ros2.tools.gradle.JavaAmentPluginExtension.this$dist$invoke$2(JavaAmentPluginExtension.groovy)
>   at
>   org.ros2.tools.gradle.JavaAmentPluginExtension$1.methodMissing(JavaAmentPluginExtension.groovy)
>   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
>   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:958)
>   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1286)
>   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1219)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:64)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:160)
>   at
>   org.ros2.tools.gradle.JavaAmentPluginExtension$1.beforeResolve(JavaAmentPluginExtension.groovy:69)
>   at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:382)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:364)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:352)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:339)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:231)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:150)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.beforeResolve(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.performPreResolveActions(DefaultConfiguration.java:674)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$400(DefaultConfiguration.java:141)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$1.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:618)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:611)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.lambda$resolveExclusively$4(DefaultConfiguration.java:592)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$SafeExclusiveLockImpl.withLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:289)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveExclusively(DefaultConfiguration.java:590)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:576)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:554)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.resolve.DependencyResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(DependencyResolverImpl.java:153)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.resolve.DependencyResolverImpl.getDependencies(DependencyResolverImpl.java:537)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.resolve.DependencyResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(DependencyResolverImpl.java:131)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.DependencyResolver$resolveDependencies.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalProjectBuilderImpl$_getSourceSets_closure1.doCall(ExternalProjectBuilderImpl.groovy:440)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
>   at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
>   at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
>   at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)    at
>   org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
>   at
>   org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
>   at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
>   at
>   org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:163)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:198)
>   at org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection$all$1.call(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalProjectBuilderImpl.getSourceSets(ExternalProjectBuilderImpl.groovy:240)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalProjectBuilderImpl.doBuild(ExternalProjectBuilderImpl.groovy:101)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalProjectBuilderImpl.buildAll(ExternalProjectBuilderImpl.groovy:70)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.buildAll(ExtraModelBuilder.java:101)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder$1$1.create(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:104)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withLenientState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:134)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:100)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>   at
>   ..............................................................................................
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Building the `ros2_java_examples` from the command line also fails but with a different error.

```
ros2_java_examples\rcljava_examples> gradle build
> Task :checkAmentProperties FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkAmentProperties'.
> Missing Ament Gradle property: ament.build_space
```

Comment: Does the command line `gradlew build` complete without errors for you?

Comment: Unfortunately running "gradlew build" does not run. It returns a similar stack-trace - the same without the intelij part. It seems that this project requires some additional setup before it can be build.

Comment: True, so make sure it builds outside in the IDE and then try to import it again.

Comment: I agree, a command line approach helps focus on what is important. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this issue was not resolved, it was possible to work-arround it, by using directly the command line as also mentioned in the comments.

Before building the ROS2 Java Examples all the previous steps need to have been followed.